# Error 0xc0000005 when applying themida in the dll

Tags: encryption, dll, dll-injection

I have a dll that I'm applying some protections to, but when I do the protection with themida I always open the executable I get error 0xc0000005 if I go back to the normal dll without themida protection the executable opens normally.

Has anyone experienced this problem with themida?

[image]

Comment: That error is *Access Violation*, which isn't going to help much.

Comment: Exactly what 'protection' do you wish to achieve with this 'Themida'? (Note: For the first glance, it requires ring0 protected CPU-mode, which is meant for the kernel, not for user-applications.)

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond i want to avoid anti debug, anti dump, memory protection,
resource encryption and obfuscation.

Comment: (I think you got all of those. Jokes aside, don't put sensitive information into your dll, then you won't need such malware. (Yes, if it worked, it would be classified as malware.))

Answer (score 0):

You should pack your executable and use the XBundler feature of Themida to embed your packed DLL.  If that doesn't suit your needs you need to use "Protect as DLL Plugin" to increase compatibility with host applications if you're injecting your DLL